# How to pass postman api data in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, http

I tried to pass json data manually from Postman API and it is working fine, as shown below. How to pass all json data from Postman API in Angular?

Component:

```
logs = [{
  "FPO_Name": "sample",
  "FarmerCode": "sample",
  "FarmerName": "sample",
  "Sur_Name": "sample",
  "Father_Name": "sample",
  "Farmer_Dob": "1/1/1990 12:00:00 AM",
  "Farmer_Address1": "sample",
  "Farmer_Address2": "sample",
  "Farmer_Country": "sample",
  "Farmer_State": "sample",
  "Farmer_District": "sample",
  "Farmer_Taluk": "sample",
  "Farmer_Panchayat": "sample",
  "Farmer_Village": "sample",
  "Farmer_Pincode": "123456",
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Mobile_No": "1234567890",
  "RegisterDate": "01-01-2001",
  "LatitudeAndLongitude": " ",
  "BankAccountNo": "",
  "BankName": "",
  "NoOfAcres": "",
  "FarmerKYC": "sample"
}];

constructor() { }

getdetails() {
  return from([this.logs]);
}
```

Comment: Please read about how to make HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

```
    sendHttpCall(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/yourBS/yourAPI';
    const body = {
        firstName, lastName // can be a JSON object
    }
    const headers = new Headers(
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
    return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers});
    }
```

You don't need to stringify your multiple JSON objects

Comment: Thanks, but my full code of backend.service.ts is `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class BackendService {
  

  logs = [] ];
  
  
  constructor() { }
  
  getdetails() {
    return from([this.logs]);
  }

}
``. So i need to replace the above code instead of logs...

Comment: You need to write a network service that will actually be responsible for performing this API call for you. The code posted by @Venkat seems legit and should work, but ideally you should place this code in a separate network service and call it from your respective component file.

Comment: Okay, but am getting response in console as "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." In app.component.html I used `<li *ngFor="let person of people$">{{person.FarmerCode}}</li>`. In app.component.ts I used `export class AppComponent {
  people$;
  title = 'demojsontable';
  constructor(private peopleService:PeopleService,private http:HttpClient){
  }
  fetchPeople() {
    this.people$ = this.peopleService.fetchPeople();
  }
}`

Comment: I worked and finally i got console error as "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.kanchikart.in/api/test_details/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." . How to solve the same?